# Get document title

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, meta-tags

I have a script which allows to retrieve meta content from any website: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnUK7/)

I would like to retrieve the document title instead so I tried:

```
    $.each($foop.find("head[title]"), function(idx, item) {
        lnk = $(item).attr("title");
        $('<div>' + lnk + '</div>').appendTo($('#meta'));
    });
```

And:

```
    $.each($foop.find("document[title]"), function(idx, item) {
        lnk = $(item).attr("title");
        $('<div>' + lnk + '</div>').appendTo($('#meta'));
    });
```

And many more variations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How about just using `$('title')` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your callback :

```
var title = $foop.find('title').text();
console.log(title);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/naTAx/)

Comment: Don't put the code I gave you in the `each` callback : you're executing it for each meta tag. See my fiddle.